# How can I fix my WPA-EAP certificate problem?

Tags: wireless, networking, ssl, wpa2

I'm trying to connect my school's WiFi which has WPA-EAP. Everything else can connect to it except my ubuntu machine. I can connect on my HTC ONE X Android, OS X, Windows XP & 7, and iOS devices.

So the problem seems to be about either mine or their certificate. I don't really care if they have a valid certificate or not (I'll deal with that in another way). So if this certificate check can be disabled but I can connect, I'm cool with it.

In their own documentation for connecting, they mentioned no certificate from my side is needed.

[Here's my syslog](https://gist.github.com/alFReD-NSH/9175737e622144f71ec3).

I'm having Ubuntu 13.04 64bit on a lenovo E135 laptop and some more info:

```
alfred-nsh@alFiPad:~/repos$ lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

alfred-nsh@alFiPad:~/repos$ uname -a
Linux alFiPad 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am using the propitiatory driver, but I don't really have problem connecting to other networks.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1682158.html I internet wasn't working. Now my wifi connection down sometimes ... sometimes it don't connect anymore for a while ...

Comment: I have realized this is a bug in Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1104476

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have the same issue here (UQAM), it should have a certificate but, it does not. When you connect for the first time, it wont set it properly so, you need to go to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and find your connection name, edit the file. You should see this line:

```
system-ca-certs=true
```

change it to

```
system-ca-certs=false
```

If the line does not exist, add it below the `[802-1x]` section.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, using Protected EAP (PEAP), not LEAP or FAST or Tunneled TLS in my case, and got it working by leaving "Anonymous identity" (huh?) empty, PEAP version: Automatic, Inner authentication: MSCHAPv2.

Then chose No CA Certificate Authority certificate .... and confirm the subsequent warning with Ignore. (Even a friendly soul at your IT provides you a *.cer, try without first; the trouble is that if it’s self-signed or it’s Verified By root isn't known to your Ubuntu, this causes more trouble than it helps you.)

PS: The system-ca-certs option doesn't seem to appear (anymore?) in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have a certificat installed on your laptop

```
TLS: Certificate verification failed, error 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate) depth 0 for '/C=MY/ST=Kuala Lumpur/L=Mont Kiara/O=Funk Software Asia Pacific/OU=Technical Department/CN=Server'
Apr 29 17:16:22 alFiPad wpa_supplicant[952]: eth1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-TLS-CERT-ERROR reason=1 depth=0 subject='/C=MY/ST=Kuala Lumpur/L=Mont Kiara/O=Funk Software Asia Pacific/OU=Technical Department/CN=Server' err='unable to get local issuer certificate'
```

could you check if you have a certificat in your store ?

Do you use wpa_supplicant ?

Nikos

Comment: I don't need any certificate to connect, as they documented and as I connect with my phone.

Comment: Yeah, actually it's wpa_supplicant that is trying to connect!

Comment: How do I get to view all the certificates stored in my computer? I am very new to computer security stuff. Command-by-command listing will be helpful.