# I cannot connect to WIFI network due to 'missing CA certificate'

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a Samsung laptop with built-in wifi capabilities but when attempting to connect to my university's wifi I am suddenly unable to do so.

I apparently don't have a CA certificate though I have downloaded 2 and tried a few suggestions as suggested on various forums.

I have connected to this same WIFI connection (even connecting the day before yesterday) but I am suddenly unable to connect.

Please let me know of any other details which I should provide (I am not very technologically savy.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constantly asked for WiFi password and CA certificate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456970/constantly-asked-for-wifi-password-and-ca-certificate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/287804/how-can-i-fix-my-wpa-eap-certificate-problem

Answer (score 0):

Your university probably uses WPA2 Enterprise authentication. This is probably set up to have a PKI, or at the very least encrypt the authentication. The CA certificate is the one that signed the certificate of the RADIUS server handling the authentication. I think it would be best to contact the IT helpdesk and ask them for the CA certificate.