# I need to get my schools ca certificate onto my computer

Tags: wireless, certificates

I have the CA certificate on my mac book but I need to send it to my ubuntu laptop so I can access school wifi. How would I go about it?

Comment: These two questions and answers may be useful: 1. [Constantly asked for WiFi password and CA certificate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456970/constantly-asked-for-wifi-password-and-ca-certificate) and 2. [How can I fix my WPA-EAP certificate problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287804/how-can-i-fix-my-wpa-eap-certificate-problem).

Comment: Can't you use a USB drive?

Answer (score 3):

You're not telling us your version of Ubuntu, but I'm trusting it's recent enough so that the current set of instructions on the official Ubuntu documentation are sufficient.

You can find it here: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store

It includes both the installation and the conversion if it is passed to you in a different format.

In the former case, what you need to is run the following in a terminal window:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates
$ sudo cp <your_school_certificate_file> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

If there are errors, which can refer to the file being in a wrong format (e.g. DER, when it must be in PEM), you can attempt to resolve it by formatting the file, again, in the terminal:

```
$ sudo openssl x509 -inform der -outform pem -in <your_school_certificate_file.der> -out <your_school_certificate_file.crt>
```

Comment: Looks much better now. Also, these comments might get deleted, since they are merely "chat" - but again please come to [meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) or the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) if you seek any clarification.

Comment: Will do, cheers!